# Source Code Inside - Using Delete on a element after insertion in Linked List implementation breaks the whole application

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

**Linked List Class**

```
    class LinkedList
    {
    protected:
        class Element
        {
        private:
            Element *next;
            int data;
        public:
            ~Element() {};
            Element() {};
            Element(int value): next(NULL), data(value) {};
            Element(Element *elem, int value): next(elem), data(value) {};

            void setNext(Element *elem) {next = elem;}
            void setValue(int value) {data = value;}
            Element *getNext() const {return next;}
            int getValue() const {return data;}
        };

        Element *head;
        Element *tail;
    public:
        LinkedList(): head(NULL), tail(NULL) {};
        ~LinkedList() {};

        Element* returnHead() {return head;};
        Element* returnTail() {return tail;};
        void setTail(Element *elem) {tail = elem;};
        void setHead(Element *elem) {head = elem;};
        // Basic functions
        void print();
        void printEnds();
        void insertFront(int value);
        void insertAfter(int afterValue, int value);
        void deleteAt(int value);
        void reverse();


        // Question functions
        void mthElemLast(int m);
        void makeConnection();
        bool isCyclic();
        void weave();
        void removeDup();
        void deleteMiddle();
        void partition(int value);
        void palindrome();
        void sumList(Element *head1, Element *head2);
        void createIntersection(LinkedList *L1, LinkedList *L2, LinkedList *L3);
        void getIntersection(LinkedList *L1, LinkedList *L2);
    };
```

Insert Front Function

```
    void LinkedList::insertFront(int value)
    {
        Element *newElem = new Element(value);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newElem;
            tail = newElem;
        }
        else
        {
            newElem->setNext(head);
            head = newElem;
        }
    // delete newElem ------------> Adding this line Breaks the complete Linked List
    }
```

Here above I have displayed my Linked List implementation using raw pointers. The problem I am facing is when I add a new element to the list in the front I create a new Element() add it to the list and make necessary adjustments to the list to make sure head is updated.

But when I delete the temporarily created element, it breaks my complete linked list and I am unable to understand why.

If I choose not to delete the temporary element, it creates memory leaks.

Help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Deleting a list element while it's part of the list will corrupt the list and lead to undefined behaviour. You're trying to fix your memory leak in the wrong place.

Comment: @molbdnilo So what should be done? So that I avoid memory leak and still maintain the functionality.

Comment: You must have heard about destructors by now.

Comment: @molbdnilo newElem is dynamically allocated, no destructor will be called over it. I think.

Comment: You should destroy the list elements when the list is destroyed.

Comment: when posting source code, remove parts that are not relevant to the question/problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

The is fine just as it is, without the call to delete.  You say:

> If I choose not to delete the temporary element

however, the object pointed to by newElem is *not* temporary.  It is allocated on the heap and is now part of the linked list.

```
    void LinkedList::insertFront(int value)
    {
        Element *newElem = new Element(value);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newElem;
            tail = newElem;
        }
        else
        {
            newElem->setNext(head);
            head = newElem;
        }
        // No need to delete newElem, it is not a temporary object
    }
```